# Heteroskedasticity in a Linear Mixed Model with identical & fraternal twins using SAS PROC MIXED

Tags: mixed-model, heteroscedasticity, sas, paired-data

I have a dataset with identical twin pairs and fraternal twin pairs. I want to examine the relationship between an outcome variable ("DEPENDENT") and a number of other variables ("INDEPENDENT").  However, I can't run a normal OLS regression because each twin's dependent variable is correlated with their co-twin's (for my purposes, this is a nuisance).

The way I have been dealing with this is to use SAS PROC MIXED and include a random intercept defined by twin cluster (FAMILYID). Here is my syntax:

```
proc mixed method=ml covtest noclprint; 
  class FAMILYID; 
  model DEPENDENT = INDEPENDENT/solution; 
  random intercept/sub=FAMILYID type=un gcorr; 
run;
```

When I do this, I get a covariance parameter estimate for the "FAMILYID" as well as a residual term.  My understanding is that this decomposes the variability into "within-cluster" variability (residual estimate) and "between-cluster" variability (FAMILYID estimate).  I get the intraclass correlation coefficient for the family clusters by computing:  (FAMILYID estimate) divided by (FAMILYID estimate + residual estimate).

However, I realized that I probably have a heteroskedasticity issue, because fraternal twin pair members are likely to be markedly less similar to each other than identical twin pair members are.

I revised my syntax to this:

```
proc mixed method=ml covtest noclprint; 
  class FAMILYID; 
  model DEPENDENT = INDEPENDENT/solution; 
  random intercept/sub=FAMILYID group=TWINTYPE type=un gcorr; 
run;
```

Where TWINTYPE signifies whether the twin pair is identical or fraternal. 
When I do this, I get one FAMILYID estimate for fraternal twins, one FAMILYID estimate for identical twins, and one residual term.  So -- this means that I have told my model to make different "between-cluster" estimates for identical and fraternal twins -- but isn't it still disregarding twin type when it calculates the residual term?  And if the residual term reflects the "within-cluster" variability, isn't it a problem that it doesn't take into consideration that there is likely to be LESS variability within an identical twin pair on the outcome variable and MORE variability within a fraternal twin pair?

So I guess my question is one of two things:

1. Is there syntax that would leave me with a between-cluster estimate for identical twins and fraternal twins, and then a residual term for identical twins and fraternal twins?  OR
2. Am I fundamentally confused about how all of this works, and if so, what am I missing?